# read file descriptor multiple times

Tags: c, file-io, file-descriptor

I just dont understand what is wrong with my code, The goal is to encrypt one file using other file as a key using bitwise xor. It works, the problem is that the while is executed only one time and thats not enough. The if statement in the while is in case the key is shorter than the input file.
fd_in,fd_key and fd_out are the file descriptors.

```
while ((numOfBytes = read(fd_in, buf, 4096))!=0){
    numOfBytes_key=read(fd_key, buf_key, numOfBytes);
    if (numOfBytes>numOfBytes_key){
        lseek(fd_in, -(numOfBytes - numOfBytes_key), SEEK_CUR);
        lseek(fd_key, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < numOfBytes_key; i++){
        buf_out[i] = buf[i] ^ buf_key[i];
    }
    write(fd_out, buf_out, numOfBytes_key); 
}
```

Comment: Check for an error: `if(numOfBytes_key != numOfBytes) break;`

Comment: Are you sure the reads aren't returning errors? If the key couldn't be read, numOfBytes_key would be negative and that could mess all kinds of things up.

Comment: Also, why "dumb" the data down to the key size?  Why not keep rewinding and reading the key file until you have the right number of bytes?  Imagine if the key was only 1 byte long; you would read 4096 bytes of the data file, discover you only had 1 byte of key, throw away 4095 bytes of data, and then re-read them on the next iteration.

Comment: Posting a small but complete and compilable program would help.  See http://www.sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

I guess that read functions can mess things up, since reading from empty, non existing ect file will return -1.Thus, rest of computations will fall. Try to avoid that by including if firective:

```
while ((numOfBytes = read(fd_in, buf, 4096))!=0)
{
    numOfBytes_key=read(fd_key, buf_key, numOfBytes);
    if (numOfBytes>numOfBytes_key && (numOfBytes >= 0) &&(numOfBytes_key >= 0 ))
    {
        lseek(fd_in, -(numOfBytes - numOfBytes_key), SEEK_CUR);
        lseek(fd_key, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < numOfBytes_key; i++){
        buf_out[i] = buf[i] ^ buf_key[i];
    }
    write(fd_out, buf_out, numOfBytes_key); 
}
```